# Best Way to connect from spring boot to Elasticsearch without deprecations

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

```java
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration 
        = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
            .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
}

@Bean
public Client client() throws Exception {
    Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", esClusterName).build();
    TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings);
    client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(esHost), esPort));
    return client;
}
```

I have been trying to connect to elasticsearch from spring boot using following techniques:

1. RestHighLevelClient & TransportClient
2. Custom binary port : 9300

as these techniques are deprecated.

Please help me with best recommended solution to this.

Thanks,
Dilip

Answer (score 0):

You can probably allow the auto-configuration to create the client for you, so it isn't necessary to create the bean. Set the configuration properties if needed:

```
spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=http://localhost:9300
```

All properties can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.data).